# PHP_CodeSniffer returns exit status 1 or 2 in PhpStorm instead of showing warnings about violations

Tags: phpstorm, phpcodesniffer, phpcs

## Problem

PHP_CodeSniffer runs fine in my console, but gives me problems when I try to use it in PhpStorm. In should give me warnings about violations when I'm working in the editor. Currently it just returns `phpcs: exit status 1` and `phpcs: exit status 2` in the event log.

[Here](https://tppr.me/JefTi) is a screenshot that illustrates the problem. And [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/06/using-php-code-sniffer-in-phpstorm/) is a link to a blog post from PhpStorm of how it should work.

## What I've tried

I reinstalled the latest version of PHP_CodeSniffer globally and reconfigured the tool in my PhpStorm preferences without any luck.

## Question

What can I do to make PHP_CodeSniffer work again by showing me helpful warnings instead of returning exit status codes in the event log?

Comment: 1) what server type do you have at File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP 2) can you successfully validate php_codesniffer at File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Quality Tools? 3) I would suggest to contact PhpStorm support directly to troubleshoot IDE configuration issues using Help | Contact Support

Comment: Thanks for your questions! I unfortunately can't find any server type under Languages & Frameworks > PHP. I can indeed successfully validate php_codesniffer.

Comment: I mean: is it a local PHP server or a remote, Docker, vagrant?

Comment: I'm using a local Symfony server via Docker.

Comment: Well, that's a lot of stuff to check then. I suggest to contact PhpStorm support directly via Help | Contact Support - it would be more convenient to share logs, screenshots & sensitive data that way. First of all a log (Help > Show log in ...) should be checked for any detailed messages. Then, a configuration of phpcs should be checked.

Comment: Thank you, I will!